# How to remove old sign from android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, sign

I've used Android Studio's [app-sign](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) to sign my App, and configed build process automatically sign my apk. But I forget my key, and when my build my app, I get such exception,

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.  Failed to read
>   key xxApp from store "C:\Users\^-^\Desktop\app.jks": Keystore was
>   tampered with, or password was incorrect

And my app is not released now. I want to know how to remove the old sign, and use a new sign?

Can someone help?

Comment: see the sign config project > app > build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always re-sign an app with a different (new) key, however with a different key you won't be able to upload updates to Play Store and even update the app directly on the device with such APK. The same key must be used throughout the lifetime of the application in the OS and Store, otherwise it won't be recognized as 'the same application`, so in this sense, if you forgot the password to your key, there is practically nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I've not upload my app to the online store, and my app is android, it just before the release. So I can resign it with no bad influence.

Comment: Indeed, If you haven't deployed to store yet, just create a new certificate :) But don't loose it or credentials afterwards! Good luck